# How to use java .class file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm currently studying a Java course, and one of the assignments requires me to use (import) a class inside a .class file.

I'm currently using Visual Studio Code, and I can't seem to find a way to import the class into my Java code.

We are not given the .java code. From what I can tell, Visual Studio Code does not support the use of .class files.

Comment: *Usually* when you're given external class files they should be bundled inside a jar file. But a directory containing class files can also be on the classpath.

Comment: Surely this just refers to the `import` statement?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have both classes in the same directory, like in this example. Say you have class A

```
public class A {
    public int fun() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

to use class A from class B in the same directory, you just declare a type A in your B

```
class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        int i = a.fun();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

this will print `0`.

This works because both classes are in the same directory, and class A is declared public.

Being in the same directory, with no package declaration, means that both classes are in the default package, this is the easiest case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .class file is in your project directory or in a directory included in your classpath.

Create a new Java file (e.g., Main.java) in the same directory or package.

Use the class in your code:

```
// Main.java

package com.example; // If the class is in a package

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Use the fully qualified name of the class
        com.example.MyClass myObject = new com.example.MyClass();

        // Call methods on the object
        myObject.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Remember to replace com.example and MyClass with the actual package and class names of your .class file.

Answer (score -1):

as I know, intellij idea can decompile the .class file depends on the build in decompile plugin, while the extension named 'Java Decompiler' in vscode marketplace works a little complex. maybe you can take a try, use the 'Java Decompiler' extension or take a look in the intellij idea.

Comment: You don't need to decompile a .class file just to use it. That should only be necessary if you want to edit it.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dgileadi.java-decompiler.
The ext can help you view the original source code of .class file.

On the other hand, what you talked is auto-import feature, which is suported by vscode now.